# How does NSScrollView implement such a content view?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

[image]

This is what I saw in another application. Its NSScrollView view does not know how to achieve cross-border.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been built in to AppKit since Yosemite (macOS 10.10). If your scroll view is adjacent to your toolbar or titlebar, you usually shouldn't have to do anything to make the content show up blurred under the top bars.

If it's not working, you may need to add `NSWindow.StyleMask.fullSizeContentView` to your window's `styleMask` and adjust your content view layout using the window's `contentLayoutRect` or `contentLayoutGuide` to explicitly put content behind the top bars.

Watch [WWDC 2014 Session 220: Adopting Advanced Features of the New UI of OS X Yosemite](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/220/). It discusses the behavior and API in the section titled “Titlebars and Toolbars”, which starts around 7m03s.

### UPDATE

Looking at your screen shot again, I notice that the content under the top bars isn't actually blurred, so this isn't a case of the built-in AppKit behavior.

I believe what the app is doing is using `.fullSizeContentView` in the window's `styleMask`, and also setting the window's `titlebarAppearsTransparent` property to true. Then the app is adding a view with partial transparency across the top of the window, overlaying the top part of the scroll view.

The `titlebarAppearsTransparent` property is also discussed in the WWDC video I linked above.